# What means uses in github actions workflows steps?

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions

I am following [this tutorial](https://leonardqmarcq.com/posts/github-actions-cicd-elastic-beanstalk) about the gitHub actions, but I do not understand what is (and what does), the "uses" key (**uses**: actions/checkout@v2):

what is actions/checkout@v2?

```
name: example-workflow
on: [push]
jobs:
  example-job:
    steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
            with:
                node-version: '14'
                cache: 'npm'
        - run: npm install
        - run: npm test
```

Answer (score 1):

`uses` signifies that the step references an action and will call that action. The most common format is `uses: owner/repo@version`, which will cause the runner to clone the repository `github.com/owner/repo` and checks out `version` then looks for an `action.yml` to figure out what to do next.

So:

- actions/checkout@v2 will:

  - download: https://github.com/actions/checkout/tree/v2
  - parse the `action.yml` [to find the entrypoint](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/ee0669bd1cc54295c223e0bb666b733df41de1c5/action.yml#L74-L77)
  - execute `dist/index.js`

`uses` can also reference a docker container or a local path to a folder that contains an `action.yml` file.

[These `actions` are reusable bits of code that are shared by companies and the community, you can find many of them in the marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?category=&query=&type=actions&verification=) (though some authors haven't published their actions there).